# len() shows invalid syntax when define function

Tags: python, function, recursion

```
def prodListePos_rec(l, len(l)):
    if (len(l)>0):
        if l[len(l)-1] > 0:
            product = prodListePos_rec(l,len(l)) * l[len(l)-1]
    else:
        product = 1 
    return product

l = [1,-2, 5, 0, 6,-5]
prodListePos_rec(l,len(l))
```

I don't get why it shows the invalid syntax and what should I do if I want to call the `len()` as a recursion function?

Comment: `def prodListePos_rec(l, len(l))` You can't have a function call as a parameter.

Comment: `l[len(l)-1]` Also, `l[-1]` is the usual way of accessing the last element in a list.

Comment: You don't really need 2 parameters for this. Just have 1, the list that you are taking the product of. `len(l)` is a function of `l` -- you don't need to include it as a parameter. Also -- using `l` as a variable name is a poor choice since it looks too much like the number `1`. It is a bug waiting to happen.

Comment: Yeah, in a language like C you'd have separate `(int arr[], int len)` parameters because arrays decay to pointers in that context.  But in Python, a `list` is a first-class object that knows its own length, so you can just call `len(l)` *inside* the function.

Answer (score 2):

Function parameters must be [identifiers](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#identifiers), so `l` is fine, but `len(l)` is not.

Although, [`l` is a bad variable name since it looks like `1` and `I`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#names-to-avoid); you could use `lst` instead.

More importantly, you don't actually need to pass the `len()` around. You can simply get it inside the function.

Here's a fixed up version of your code. I added variables for values that are used more than once.

```
def prodListePos_rec(lst):
    n = len(lst)
    if n > 0:
        x = lst[n-1]
        if x > 0:
            product = prodListePos_rec(lst) * x
    else:
        product = 1
    return product

lst = [1, -2, 5, 0, 6, -5]
prodListePos_rec(lst)
```

However, the code still doesn't work because it's possible for `n > 0` and `x <= 0`, so `product` never gets defined. Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/wja/testdir/tmp.py", line 13, in <module>
    prodListePos_rec(lst)
  File "/home/wja/testdir/tmp.py", line 10, in prodListePos_rec
    return product
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'product' referenced before assignment
```

Answer (score 0):

When you define function, you write *names* of parameters in parethesis.

`l` is a name of parameter. When you call a function, python will "replace" `l` with it's value to calculate result of function.

`len(l)` is not a name, it's an expression. So you can't use it as a name.

You can change your function to this

```py
def prodListePos_rec(l, len_l):
    if (len_l>0):
        if l[len_l-1] > 0:
            product = prodListePos_rec(l,len_l) * l[len_l-1]
    else:
        product = 1 
    return product

p = [1,-2, 5, 0, 6,-5]
prodListePos_rec(p,len(p))
```

`len_l` is a name of parameter. I changed `l` to `p` in function calling, to not confuse variables with parameters

Or simply you can do that

```py
def prodListePos_rec(l):
    if (len(l)>0):
        if l[len(l)-1] > 0:
            product = prodListePos_rec(l,len(l)) * l[len(l)-1]
    else:
        product = 1 
    return product

p = [1,-2, 5, 0, 6,-5]
prodListePos_rec(p)
```

In this case `len(l)` is an expression, that calctulates length of a given list.

Answer (score 0):

> def prodListePos_rec(l, len(l)): ->> len(l) is inbuilt function to
> find length of list, string, etc.

which cannot be used as variable to define the attribute of defined

> function --> def prodListePos_rec(l, len(l)):

instead use

```
def prodListePos_rec(l, len_of_l):
    product = 1
    if (len_of_l)>0):
        if l[len_of_l)-1] > 0:
            product = prodListePos_rec(l,len_of_l)) * l[len_of_l)-1] 
    return product

l = [1,-2, 5, 0, 6,-5]
print(prodListePos_rec(l,len(l)))
```

Remember: this is a recursive function. So, It will not enter else block.